# Как мне получить содержание пасты с pastebin в виде double а не String?

Tags: java

У меня есть такой код

```
public class ParsePastebin {
    public static String get(String url) throws Exception {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream()); sc.hasNext(); )
              sb.append(sc.nextLine());
           return sb.toString();
        }
```

и вот как я его использую

```
ParsePastebin.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/8HEuGxey");
```

но как мне получить не String, а double? тк в этой пасте находится `1.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам точно известно, что в тексте будет значение 1.2, то можно использовать метод `Double.parseDouble()` он принимает в качестве аргумента строку, и возвращает `Double`, и тип возвращаемого значения в методе тоже изменить на `double`, java автоматически распакует ссылочный `Double` до примитива. Однако учтите, что если текст не будет соответствовать формату double, то будет выброшен `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: как использовать?